# Place child element above parent ::after pseudo-element?

Tags: css, parent

So how can I place a child element above its parent `::after` pseudo-element? Basically I have a div with a background image with 2 pseudo-elements: a `::before`, which is an absolute-positioned full-width and height, transparent blue and a `::after`, which is an inset box-shadow, and now I'm trying to place child elements above all the parent's pseudo-elements. How can I do that?

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/got3e2vb/ - I want the white circle to be placed above the parent's ::after pseudo-element. How can I do that?

Comment: Yep. Tried doing z-index: 99999 to one and z-index: -1 to another, still doesn't work.

Comment: Without code is difficult to help you.

Comment: First thing in the morning I'll paste my code here. I'm not at my computer right now. Still waiting for suggestions though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` is enough.

Try this:

```css
#author {
  width: 100%;
  height: 683px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('images/parallax/apartment1.jpg');
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}
#author:after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 150px #072243;
  content: ' ';
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: all .40s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .40s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .40s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .40s ease-out;
  transition: all .40s ease-out;
}
#author:before {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #1a6dd3;
  content: ' ';
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#author:hover:after {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 250px #0f3461;
  opacity: 0.9;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#author-preview {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="author">
  <div id="author-preview">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more general solution to the title:

```
#author:first-child::before  {
    //etc...
}
```